# Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug' property 'numberOfBuckets'. Expected minSdkVersion >= 21 but found 1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Have a good day everyone. I am starting my studies in Kotlin using Android Studio in its version 4.2.2. I have created a project from 0 using the IDE itself and I get the error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'
>
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug' property
> 'numberOfBuckets'.
>
> Expected minSdkVersion >= 21 but found 1

I was looking in other publications that spoke of compilation problems mainly due to incompatibilities in the dependencies included in the project, but none spoke exactly about the error that I am presenting...

The gradle module has the default code when creating the application which is the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nueva"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

The gradle project also has the default configuration that it brings when the application is created:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't have any additional implementation either in MainActivity.kt or another project file. If anyone has been through this error and fixed it please I would really appreciate if you would share with me how to eliminate this error. Maybe the solution is simple, but as I said before I am new to the world of Kotlin and I would like very much in the future to be able to be involved in the world of developing applications for smartphones. Without further ado, thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure test on a Device >= API Level 21 ? Also check from `Settings for New Projects` to be selected Android 11.0 (R) or Android 9.0 Pie (check also these versions are installed in sdk manager)

Comment: I am using android studio emulator based on pixel 4xl with API 29 (Android 10.0). I have Android 10.0 (Q) and Android 11.0 (R) sdk. I don't have Android 9.0 (pie) available. should I install it then?

Comment: Yes, install also this and then in the  `Settings for New Projects ` select Android 9.0 Pie and click apply.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. I integrated sdk 28 and the application worked without problems. I'm already taking my first steps, thanks to your help

Comment: If this helped you, please accept , thanks!